# IOS7 doesnt authenticate Gamecenter test ID ; apparently works fine in IO6

Tags: unity-game-engine, ios7, game-center, xcode5

IOS7 doesnt authenticate Gamecenter test ID ; apparently works fine in IO6

Is any-thing i need to reset/set before testing.

i tried reset device from setting / reset / reset all settings

i tried with different ios7 device

Comment: So I'm unsure why you got voted down, you said what you tried and what you did, that's great. I can only guess you didn't give evidence or searching other things is all. I hate downvotes without explanation, since I was downvoted because I didn't know 2 words were the same thing. Getting punished for learning is the opposite of this site's reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the docs for the older and the newer ones, the function names changed. For example, report function takes array, used to be single